# How to add text "Before" Extracted Text?

Tags: imacros

I tried to collect data myself on social media, and I want to add text before the extract results.

Hire My Code :

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1

TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:/* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\//, ''); s;")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*@*.* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=class:_c24<SP>_2ieq EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/Birth \\date/, ''); s;") 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt
```

I use this code to remove Special Character  ̶"/̶"

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\//, ''); s;")
```

I use this code because i want to remove unwanted text "B̶i̶r̶t̶h̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ 12 April 1992"

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/Birth \\date/, ''); s;")
```

the results of the code :

```
Hilda
100992837
hilda8872@gmail.com
12 April 1992
```

Now... I want to add text to the results like this:

```
Name : Hilda
User ID : 100992837
Email : hilda8872@gmail.com
Date of Birth : 12 April 1992
```

What should I do ?
which one should i change?
please, this is my college assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried use ADD !EXTRACT ..., but the result contains special characters.

```
ADD !EXTRACT Name<SP>:<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

ADD !EXTRACT User<SP>ID<SP>:<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:/* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\//, ''); s;")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

ADD !EXTRACT Email<SP>:<SP
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*@*.* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt

ADD !EXTRACT Date<SP>of<SP>Birth<SP>:<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=class:_c24<SP>_2ieq EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/Birth \\date/, ''); s;") 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=extract.txt
```

Result :

```
"Name : ","Hilda"
"User ID : ","100992837"
"Email : ","hilda8872@gmail.com"
"Date of Birth : ","12 April 1992"
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by Add this Code :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/search/ ATTR=NAME:query CONTENT=Nama<SP>:<SP>{{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/search/ ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\CPS\Desktop FILE=extract.txt
```

Result :

```
Name : Hilda
```